# Xcode 6 App Stops AutoSizing When Launch Images Added

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, image, launch

I began a calculator app for the iPhone 5/5s using xCode v5 with storyboard.  I've since upgraded to xCode 6 and have nearly completed the app.  I tested the app on my iPhone 5, and on the iPhone 6 and 6 plus using the xCode simulators.  The app fills the screen of my iPhone 5 and autoscales to completely fill the simulator screens for the 6 and 6 plus.  Exactly what I wanted!  However, when I added launch images to my project, the app no longer autoscales when running on the 6 and 6 plus simulators.  I've followed Apple's recommendations for launch image sizes, and have tried dragging the launch images into my project and using an asset catalog.  Both stop the app from autoscaling.  What I'm currently seeing is a launch image that completely fills the screen of the iPhone 5/6/6 plus for approximately 1 second.  Then the calculator appears, completely filling the screen of my iPhone 5, but remains that same size, filling only a portion of the iPhone 6 and 6 plus screens.  I want the calculator app to completely fill the screens when running on the iPhone 5, 6 and 6 plus.  Why does autoscaling stop when launch images are added and how do I continue to enable autoscaling after the launch images are added to my project?  Thanks in advance for guidance.

Turkey day morning: I solved my problem!  With great skepticism, I tried the solution linked below and it solved my problem.  I added launch images (drag and drop).  The calculator displays correctly on my iPhone 5, and also displays correctly when running on the iPhone 6 and 6 plus simulators.  Don't understand why the linked solution below works, so it's something I'll just have to accept.  My thanks to Matt Palmer for posting this on his blog:

http://matthewpalmer.net/blog/2014/09/10/iphone-6-plus-launch-image-adaptive-mode/

Comment: Hi Cheesehead1957, please do not add solutions to the question, add an own answer instead and please include the solution, not just a link (which has to be included as reference and credit for the owner). So please remove your solution from the question, create a good answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

using a LaunchScreen.xib as LaunchScreen is 'cleaner', instead of generating 6 different images for a LaunchScreen Asset in the Media Catalog.

Don't forget to check 'Use as Launch Screen'

Answer (score 0):

You should try this.

Disable Auto Layout and Size Classes.
[image]

and do this for all subViews in you XIB

[image]